# NLog Selectively flush async target wrappers

Tags: c#, asynchronous, logging, nlog

I have a large number of async target wrappers created like this:

```
                var fileTarget = new FileTarget("file_"+unique_id)
                {
                    FileName = $"{unique_id}.log"),
                    Layout = layout_string,
                    DeleteOldFileOnStartup = false,
                    KeepFileOpen = true,
                    AutoFlush = false
                };

                var asyncFileTarget =
                    new NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper(fileTarget, 10000, NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Block);
                asyncFileTarget.Name = unique_id;

                m_job_logger_factory.Configuration.AddTarget(asyncFileTarget);
                m_job_logger_factory.Configuration.AddRule(TranslateEnum(logLevel), NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, asyncFileTarget, assignedLogger.Name);
                m_job_logger_factory.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Each target has a separate logger assigned to it.
Then I log a couple of lines to each of the created targets through their assigned loggers. 
Nothing is logged to the file yet, as they are async, and the queue is not full.

Now, if I do

```
               Target t = m_job_logger_factory.Configuration.FindTargetByName(unique_id);
               t.Flush((e) => { });
```

I'd expect only the unique_id file to have the new logs, instead I find all the files updated (as if I had called flush on the LogManager/LogFactory, and not this specific target).

Is this configuration incorrect or is this a bug with target.Flush(AsyncContinuation)?

Comment: What's the NLog version and what does the internal log reports (trace level). See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging. I checked the code, flush of a target only flushes that target (and wrapped targets)

Comment: anyway, maybe explain what you are trying to do with those file targets and separate flushes. It sounds like a XY problem. I also don't think you need more than *one* file target.